# SQl select null value using OR operator

Tags: sql

i have left joining with `exam_admission_student` table i want to select only those values whose `status = 1` or those which is not contain in `Exam_admission_stutend` table

```
select ps.name,
       ps.uni_registration,
       eas.enrolled_in_exam,
       ps.id,
       ps.father_name,
       ps.student_cnic,
       sps.id,
       sc.id 
from profile_student ps  
left join assignment_student_program_session sps on sps.std_id=ps.id  
left join assignment_session_program sp on sp.id=sps.program_session_comb_id  
left join assignment_student_class sc on sc.std_prog_session_combid=sps.id
left join exam_admission_student eas on eas.std_class_combid=sc.id  
where  sps.status=1 
and sps.program_session_comb_id=1008 
and sps.inst_id=9 
and sc.part='part1'
and eas.status is null 
or eas.status=1
```

Comment: i have left joining with exam_admission_student table  i want to select only those values whose status =1 or those which is not contain in Exam_admission_stutend table

Comment: You need to be more specific to let others help you efficiently. Describe the nature of problem in detail and what version of SQL etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, just add a parenthesis: (assuming the status is not nullable)

```
select ps.name,
       ps.uni_registration,
       eas.enrolled_in_exam,
       ps.id,
       ps.father_name,
       ps.student_cnic,
       sps.id,
       sc.id 
from profile_student ps  
left join assignment_student_program_session sps on sps.std_id=ps.id  
left join assignment_session_program sp on sp.id=sps.program_session_comb_id  
left join assignment_student_class sc on sc.std_prog_session_combid=sps.id
left join exam_admission_student eas on eas.std_class_combid=sc.id  
where  sps.status=1 
and sps.program_session_comb_id=1008 
and sps.inst_id=9 
and sc.part='part1'
and (eas.status is null or eas.status=1)
```

Comment: Wawoo it's works thanks #zoharpeled you saved my life

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)